# Stray voltage on light fixture

Tags: switches, wire, light

I have installed a led panel on a previously existing light pole in my house. It has the feature of switching light colors if you flip the switch quickly. If the switch is left off for some time and then turned on, it reamins on the same light color. I noticed that it was switching light colors even when the switch remained off for several hours.

If I instead trip the breaker on the circuit, the led panel doesn't switch light color, because the breaker avoids the stray voltage. I thought the mechanism could be based on the charge a capacitor holds: if the capacitor holds some charge, it assumes the switch was off not for long; if it has no charge, it assumes the switch was off for a long time.

So, I measured the voltage between L and N on the light pole when the switch is off and it showed 60V AC. If I short the wires, the ampmeter shows a current measurement of 0.000A.

With the led panel connected to the light pole, I hooked up a voltmeter to the capacitor after the bridge rectifier on the PCB of the led panel power supply. After I open the switch, the voltage starts droping but only until 5V. If I disconnect the power supply from the light pole, it drops further. If I connect it again, it charges up again until 5V. So, I assume that the wires that are live and run along with the ones that go to the light pole are inducing an EMF on the light pole wires, which explains that voltage. It seems like that stray voltage, although not allowing more than a few uA to flow, it is enough to keep the capacitor charged to 5V, but not more than 5V because after that the current leakage in the capacitor is higher than the current that the induced EMF can provide. However, that charge is enough for the led panel to think that it was not off for a long time.

My question is not exactly how can I fix this specific problem but instead to learn a bit more about what is creating that EMF (if it really is induction) and, since it can be a common problem on light poles, how should have the power supply been architected to avoid this "misleading" stray voltages to affect the switching mechanism.

I have other light poles in my house where I could measure 50V stray voltage and they work fine with these switching light colors power supplies.

Comment: What is a "light pole"? The only thing I would call that is a streetlight, definitely not something you'd have in your house.

Comment: what's a `stray voltage`? ... it is unclear how a breaker avoids it ... please draw a diagram of your circuit

Comment: @Hearth, Probably I didn't get the right terminology. What I mean by light pole is the end of a conduit, containing two wires, the L and N that provide 230VAC, to which you can hook up a light, generally located in the ceiling.

Comment: @Dinis The word you want is "light fixture", I think. Or specifically the "bulb socket".

Comment: Is it on a Triac dimmer circuit switch?

Comment: Do you have an earth wire going to that location? IF so, what do you measure between L-Earth and N-Earth with the switch turned off?, and the same measurements but with the breaker off instead?

Comment: @Hearth Ok, thanks for the word sugestion :)

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 No, it's not

Comment: @brhans No, I don't have a ground wire in the light fixture, but I can try measuring the voltage between the earth wire on a close power socket.

Comment: You can inject some leakage voltage with a 1nF Plastic Y cap across the switch, to simulate stray coupling but something doesn’t sound right on the function of the LEDs with power off or the wiring of L, N.

Comment: I think you should try that. My suspicion is that your switch is switching Neutral instead of Live. And there may be just enough stray coupling between everything that your light is still seeing just enough of a voltage to make it think that the power is still there. Switching the breaker however certainly does switch Live as is should, which would explain the different behavior.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Should I connect the plastic Y cap in parallel with the switch or in series with the switch?
I'm sorry but I didn't understand how the capacitor is going to help. Since the frequency of the unintended voltage and the utility voltage is the same, I don't see how the capacitor is going to filter the unintended voltage. Can you elaborate, pls?

Comment: @brhans I've already preivously checked and the switch is switching Live, not Neutral

Comment: What i meant to say was Y cap from load to neutral to shunt leakage currents towards 0V of N.

Comment: Oh, ok, I get it now. The capacitor is going to "eat up" the stray voltage. When normal 230VAC is connected, it will eat some current but its is negletable.